# Why some people use could instead of can

Tags: modal-verbs, could-modal

Why some people use could instead of can (in the simple present tense)
For example,

> Could you open the door?

Answer (score -1):

**Could** is a modal auxiliary and so is **can**. The difference is the context it is used in.

**Can** is the more informal of the two words and is used while addressing friends and siblings (while making a request).

**Could** is the more formal of the two words. It is used while acknowledging someone elder or a respected personality. It is often used while communicating with strangers since it is more polite than the word *can* (while making a request).

Apart from the above mentioned, there are other scenarios that are taken into consideration while using the two words.

**Could** is the past tense of the modal verb **can**. Hence one must be careful while using it in affirmative or declarative sentences.

For further detailed information, [refer to this article](https://keydifferences.com/difference-between-can-and-could.html).

Hope this helps. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for your answer,
If there is a  igrammatical mistake in the text of my question(or this text), I will be happy if u mention it, thank u

Comment: @Brian Well the original question has been edited hence it is now mistake free. But I think you were trying to say "grammatical" instead of "igrammatical".

Comment: i was typing fast , i meant "grammatical " ,thanks anyway.